# Angular UI Router - Reloading to different state - refresh data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to change the state and then trigger the reload/refresh at that particular state using ui-router i had tried  location.href previously but it seems that if there is hashbang then it doesn't reload the whole page ,but i want to reload the page

```
this.$state.go(this.$state.params.returnUrl, {}, {reload: true});
```

i had tried the above code but not working for me ,where returnurl is the state where i want to take the state to.

Comment: what do you mean by "reload/refresh"? do you want to reload entire page, or you just need to force state resolving process again (resolve section/controller init/etc)?

Comment: i want to reload the entire page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**$state.go** doesn't reload the whole page, even with **reload** option set to **true**. 
To reload the page you can get result url using **$state.href**, and reload the page with **window.location**

```
// get state's relative url with populated params
// if you want to get absolute url, then you can add {absolute:true} param
window.location.href = $state.href('state.name', {param: 'value'});
// reload the page
window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some more code to identify the issue. Have you injected $state to your controller? I've used this approach before and it has worked.

Comment: are you sure its reloading the entire page ,have u checked your network monitor in developer tools whether its sending the get request to the server for components again

Comment: It does refresh the entire view + controller. I've not checked network monitor specifically, but an alert showing up in the success callback of a http request means that it's sending the GET request again.